# The sticky taste

Tags: riddle

> I have two sticky tastes.
>
> The first paints your face
>
> and, if you race,
>
> The second tells you there's no waste.

What am I?

Comment: Is this an original puzzle?

Comment: yes it is an original puzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I

> an ice lolly on a stick?

being that they are both

> "sticky" and to taste the second there is none of the first left

Comment: Close enough. But the word sticky is used in two senses.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am

> Blank paper

And you are

> A pencil with eraser

> I have two sticky tastes.

> The pencil and the eraser.

> The first paints your face

> The pencil writes on the paper.

> and, if you race,

> If someone writes something so quick that it's wrong.

> The second tells you there's no waste.

> The other end (the eraser) can fix that.

Comment: Interesting. I would say this is a second acceptable solution. So if your "face" is the blank paper, you are tasting the lead and the eraser. I don't understand how the tastes are "sticky" though. It's not the answer I had in mind, but it's a good one.